# Built-in helper for "Must" pattern in Go

Tags: go

Is there a more built-in wrapper to make a function that returns `(X, error)` successfully execute or abort, like `regexp.MustCompile`?

I'm talking about [something like this](http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/helper.go?s=576:619), but more "built-in".

Comment: If there was, the standard library would be using it. What is wrong with `template.Must()` or `regexp.MustCompile()`? It is easy to code, easy to understand.

Comment: @StephenWeinberg I was hoping for a built-in before reinventing my own, so I do things The Right Way (I'm learning). What is wrong with regexp.MustCompile is that it doesn't apply to my types. Manual coding it is, then. Oh well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Go 1.18 we can define typed `Must` instead of `interface{}`:

```
func Must[T any](obj T, err error) T {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return obj
}
```

How to use: https://go.dev/play/p/ajQAjfro0HG

```
func success() (int, error) {
    return 0, nil
}

func fail() (int, error) {
    return -1, fmt.Errorf("Failed")
}

func main() {
    n1 := Must(success())
    fmt.Println(n1)
    var n2 int = Must(fail())
    fmt.Println(n2)
}
```

Must fails inside `main`, when `fail()` returns non-nil `error`

You can even define `Must`*n* for more than 1 return parameter, e.g.

```
func Must2[T1 any, T2 any](obj1 T1, obj2 T2, err error) (T1, T2) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return obj1, obj2
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is not. The best you'll get is something like this:

```
func Must(fn func() (interface{}, error)) interface{} {
    v, err := fn()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    return v
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Must(func() (interface{}, error) {
    return template.ParseGlob(pattern)
}).(*template.Template)
```

Assuming that `template.ParseGlob(pattern)` is the call you wanted to wrap.

Go does not have parametric polymorphism, so this kind of code will end up requiring type assertions to restore the original type and so (in my opinion) is more effort than it's worth. The tidiest, idiomatic error handling you'll get for long chains of potential failure is simply to check for an error, and return it. Defer your cleanup handlers:

```
func MyFunc() (err error) {
    a, err := blah1()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer a.Close()
    b, err := blah2(a)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer b.Close()
    // ad nauseam
}
```

Long and tedious, but at least it's explicit and easy to follow. Here are two modules I wrote that are crying out for parametric polymorphism that might give you some ideas for dealing without it:

- [bitbucket.org/anacrolix/dms/futures](http://go.pkgdoc.org/bitbucket.org/anacrolix/dms/futures)
- [bitbucket.org/anacrolix/dms/cache](http://go.pkgdoc.org/bitbucket.org/anacrolix/dms/cache)

Comment: I wonder if generics would help with this now that they've landed.

Comment: Yeah, not brave enough to commit to them yet just for little things.

Comment: Same. I'm planning to come back to generics in like Go 1.19 and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a built-in mechanism would make sense since you could very well handle a non-nil error in various ways, as does the examples in the template package itself: see "[`text/template/examplefiles_test.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/examplefiles_test.go?l=60:71)", illustrating 2 different usage of '`err`':

```
// Here starts the example proper.
    // T0.tmpl is the first name matched, so it becomes the starting template,
    // the value returned by ParseGlob.
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseGlob(pattern))

    err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("template execution: %s", err)
    }
    // Output:
    // T0 invokes T1: (T1 invokes T2: (This is T2))
```

In the particular case of the helper function `(*Template) Must()`, transforming an error into an exception (panic) isn't always the right course for *all* go programs (as debated in [this thread](http://lwn.net/Articles/503452/)), and to cover all the possible way to handle an error would mean to create *a lot of* "built-in" mechanisms.

Comment: I'm not really sure why it's necessary to "cover all possible ways to handle an error." The OP isn't saying that all errors should be panics. The OP is asking if there is a 'Must' pattern to *generally* turn *some* errors into panics if they exist.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 in that case, the answer is 'no'.

Comment: Okay? I wasn't disputing that.

Comment: Yes I know you can handle the error, and no it does make sense in my case, because in my case the failure is most certainly fatal, so it's pretty much either initialise or die (hence the "must" pattern). And yes, it appears the answer is "no".

Comment: @AlexB indeed. My point was, if the answer had been 'yes', that would have involved *a lot of* other built-in functions in order to cover *all* the possible way to process an error.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem myself and decided to develop the following solution: https://github.com/boramalper/must

**Example:**

```golang
database := must.MV(sql.Open("sqlite3", "...")).(*sql.DB)
defer must.M(database.Close())

must.M(database.Ping())

// Use MustValVoid (or MVV shortly) if you don't care about
// the return value.
must.MVV(database.Exec(`
    PRAGMA foreign_key_check;
    ...
`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why all the answers here are using the `log` package, when the
source itself uses `panic`:

```
func MustCompile(str string) *Regexp {
   regexp, err := Compile(str)
   if err != nil {
      panic(`regexp: Compile(` + quote(str) + `): ` + err.Error())
   }
   return regexp
}
```

My recommendation would be instead of a generic `Must` wrapper, just implement
`Must` variants as needed in your code.

1. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.5/src/regexp/regexp.go#L305-L314