# Is it possible to get a single value from a function (which has multiple return values) during a statement?

Tags: go

Lets say for example `add(int, int)` returns and `int` and an `error`, and I want to append the int return value into a string. The way I know how to do it in go is:

```
foo := ""
bar, _ := add(1, 2)
foo += strconv.Itoa(bar)
```

However, if `add()` didn't return an error variable, I can just do `foo += strconv.Itoa(add(1, 2))`.

Is it possible to ignore the error variable during the statement to do something like that?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer (my opinion)**:  This answer is just for fun.  I **don't recommend ever using** this.  Ignoring errors is bad, and trying to compactify every line of code is a fool's errand.  This just illustrates some interesting concepts about how Go handles multiple return values, and I learned something new while writing this, so I thought I'd share.

**Related:** The more practical cousin of this problem is the "Must pattern", used by some of the standard library including [templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Must).  It involves taking a value and an error, `panic`ing if the error is not nil, and then returning the value.  See this (currently frozen) [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32219)

You need a wrapper function to do this. The multiple return values will automatically expand to fill the arguments.

See this example which matches the types of `add()`

```
func ignoreError(i int, err error) int {
    return i
}
```

Calling:

```golang
foo := ""
foo += strconv.Itoa(ignoreError(add(1, 2)))
```

---

Here's a more general alternative, which will take any number of values from another function and return the first.

```golang
func takeFirstValue(v ...interface{}) interface{} {
    if len(v) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return v[0]
}
```

Calling:

```golang
    foo := ""
    foo += strconv.Itoa(takeFirstValue(add(1, 2)).(int))
```

This option requires casting at the call site `.(int)` to restore the data type, as takeFirstValue returns `interface{}`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to ignore the error variable during the statement to do something like that?

No, Go offers no language construct for something like this.

(But you can have your own Must... functions like you'll find in package regexp or text/template.)